# Ruby: Temporarily store remote file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, carrierwave, temporary-files

I am trying to post a file to an API, which I have stored remotely using CarrierWave.

Using the local file that has not yet been uploaded using CarrierWave works well:

```
JSON.parse(RestClient.post("https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/keys/android", {
    keystore: File.new(Rails.root.join('file.keystore'))
}), symbolize_names: true)[:id]
=> 312199
```

Here is how I tried to temporarily store the file locally:

```
response = HTTParty.get model.file.url
f = Tempfile.new SecureRandom.hex
f.binmode
f.write response.body
f.flush
f.close
JSON.parse(RestClient.post("https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/keys/android", {
    keystore: File.new(f)
}), symbolize_names: true)[:id]
RestClient::BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
```

I checked that the temp file and `file.keystore` have the same contents.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that `https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/keys/android` is expecting a filename called `file.keystore` ? If the file contents are the same, what other explanation can there be?

Comment: You're right. This is soo obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your api depends on the filename being `file.keystore` but you don't care about persisting the file why not just write a file, post it, then just delete the file?

```
    response = HTTParty.get model.file.url
    file = File.open('file.keystore', 'w') do |f|
        f.binmode
        f.write response.body
    end

    JSON.parse(RestClient.post("https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/keys/android", {
        keystore: 'file.keystore' 
    }), symbolize_names: true)[:id]

    File.delete('file.keystore')
```